# How can I upload bulk images as separate nodes in drupal 8?

Tags: 8, nodes, media

I have a folder of images I am trying to bulk upload. As they will be used in galleries that can be filtered by year and location I was hoping to make them individual nodes with year and location fields that the bulk upload would fill in with a preset on each upload batch.

I've played with the media entity module and managed to upload a group of images as a single media entity but I don't really want the files grouped.

Is there a way to do this in D8 yet?
I'm fairly new to D8 so am not too sure of how things work yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DropZoneJS](https://www.drupal.org/project/dropzonejs) can auto-create media entities for every uploaded image.

Remember that you need to set up an [entity browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser) using the DropZoneJS-Widget for the bulk-upload feature.

Your image gallery is an entity reference field to media entities (unlimited cardinality).

If you are looking for a general tutorial on how to set up media entities, I found [this tutorial](https://www.electriccitizen.com/blog/media-libraries-drupal-8) quite helpful.

Comment: The whole media stuff is indeed a bit complex, because it still is in heavy development. My major tutorial was [this one](https://www.electriccitizen.com/blog/media-libraries-drupal-8). I would not recommend IEF though, for me plain entity browser was a better editor experience. Remember also this tutorial is for contrib media (<= Drupal 8.3) - it is largely the same though, you just need to pick the right version of the modules if you are using core media (>= Drupal v8.4)